# JavaFX application on Android platform is too slow (JavaFXPorts/Gluon)

Tags: java, android, javafx, javafxports, gluon

I am attempting to develop/port the classical 'Flappy Bird' game on Desktop, Android, and iOS using JavaFX with Gluon and JavaFXPorts. The application is now playable on Desktop and Android platforms, but with noticeable performance differences. The application is **TOO SLOW** on Android (slow animation).

I already did some performance tuning such as node caching, `AnimationTimer` as game loop, node recycling, parallel processing with Stream API back-port `net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport`, and among others, but the performance is still the same.

How could I make my application faster, with similar performance with the desktop version?

You can find my application's source code here: https://github.com/warrenmnocos/flappy-bird-gluon.

Mirror post: http://gluonhq.com/forums/topic/javafx-application-on-android-platform-is-too-slow-javafxportsgluon/

Comment: Did you do any profiling to see what was slow before you did this performance tuning?

Comment: @DavidConrad Profiling is done on the desktop version. Results are just fine. I haven't tried profiling on Android. It seems the animation rendering on Android is not as good as on the desktop.

Comment: But Android is where you're having the performance problem. You need to find a way to do profiling there.